# XML "xsl:for-each" same names of items?

Tags: xml, xslt, names

My document is :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="university_style.xsl"?>
    <!DOCTYPE library SYSTEM "validator.dtd">
        <university>
            <total_faculty>13</total_faculty>
            <faculty>
                <id>1</id>
                <name>name 1</name>
                <total_chairs>9</total_chairs>
                <chairs_list>
                    <chair>name 1</chair>
                    <chair>name 2</chair>
                    <chair>name 3</chair>
    ...
                </chairs_list>
            </faculty>

        </university>
```

and xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
<body>
      <table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
        <caption>total_faculty:<xsl:value-of select="university/total_faculty"/></caption>
        <tr bgcolor="#999999" align="center">
          <th>id</th>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>total chairs</th>
          <th>chairs</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="university/faculty">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="total_chairs"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <!--<p><xsl:value-of select="chairs_list"/></p> -->
              <xsl:for-each select="chairs_list">
                <p><xsl:value-of select="chair"/> </p>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
</body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to show all elements from  in new row (

chair

).
But i see either first element or all. If a use  then all list in one row.

If i use:

```
<xsl:for-each select="chairs_list">
   <p><xsl:value-of select="chair"/> </p>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I see just first element of list. How to solve it ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your `xsl:for-each` to

```
<xsl:for-each select="chairs_list/chair">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Result:

```
<p>name 1</p>
<p>name 2</p>
<p>name 3</p>
```

This adjusted `for-each` selects all `chair` elements in the `chairs_list`, loops over them and generates as output the content of the current node - `select="."` - of this loop.  Your previous `for-each` only selected the `chairs_list`, so `<xsl:value-of select="chair"/>` only has as output the first `chair` in this list.